# Static file versioning with Django

Tags: html, django, nginx, web-optimization

I am setting far-future expires headers for my CSS/Javascript so that the browsers don't ever ask for the files again once they get cached. I also have a simple versioning mechanism so that if the files change, the clients will know.

Basically I have a template tag and I do something like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{% versioned "javascript/c/c.js" %}"></script>`

which will become

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://x.com/media/javascript/c/c.min.js?123456"></script>`.

The template tag opens a file `javascript/c/c.js.v` where it finds the version number and appends it to the query string. The version is generated by a shell script (run manually for now, will probably add pre-commit hook) which checks whether the file has changed (using `git diff`).

This is all working fine, EXCEPT:

I want to implement the same kind of versioning for images as well. But images can be referenced from CSS - which is a static file (served by nginx) - so no template tag there.

What is a better approach for file versioning?

Alternatively, I am thinking about replacing the template tag with a middleware which changes all links before returning the response. That is better than the template tag, which can be mistakenly omitted. But still doesn't solve the issue of images referenced from CSS.

Also, I'm aware that having the version as part of the query string might cause trouble with certain proxies not caching the file - so I consider making the version part of the filename - for example `javascript/c/c.123456.js`.

Note: It looks like there is no way to solve this issue using Django (obviously - since I don't even serve the CSS through Django). But there has to be a solution, perhaps involving some nginx tricks.

Comment: Answer by @paluh below is your best bet. Pulling file mtimes from a file in Django is not saving you anything over directly checking the mtimes on the files in Django. It's only adding an additional layer of complexity and another point of failure (shell script running as a cron job).

Comment: Indeed, mtimes could make my setup simpler - reducing the need to run the script and the dependency on git. I usually don't trust mtimes (they could change when copying to another filesystem, or backing up, or...) - but in this case I guess it doesn't really matter, because the source tree is always in the same place. Plus, if mtimes really change for some reason, worst that happens is caches get invalidated. Not terrible.

Comment: How about a pre-deploy step in which to process the CSS files? I did something similar but not with Django. It was some custom PHP.

Comment: I first thought of a pre-commit step in which I process the files, but that would unnecessary pollute my git timeline. Pre-deploy doesn't mess my git repo, but it has another issue: you don't really get a chance to review the changes - and if something goes wrong, it'll probably be too late when you find out. I'd go with pre-commit rather than pre-deploy for easy review. Since images don't change that often, the aforementioned disadvantage is not that big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will add another step to my pre-commit script to replace all direct links with links to versioned files in the minimized CSS.

Seems there is no better way to do it. If you think of any, let me know and I'll consider marking that one as accepted answer.

Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

**Stylesheet Assets**

For your stylesheet referenced assets, you're much better off using Sass & Compass. Compass has a mixin that will automatically add version query parameters on the end of static assets referenced within a stylesheet. The version number only changes when you rebuild the stylesheet (which is trivial with `compass watch` while you develop locally).

**Template Assets**

For other files, I would actually use a post-pull hook of some kind that rewrites a python module whose sole purpose is to contain the current version.

```
/var/www/aweso.me/
    ./files/
    ./private-files/
    ./static/
    ./project/
        ./manage.py
        ./fabfile.py
        ./.gitignore
        ./base/
            ./__init__.py
            ./wsgi.py
            ./settings/
                ./__init__.py
                ./modules
                    ./__init__.py
                    ./users.py
                    ./email.py
                    ./beta.py
                    ./redis.py
                    ./haystack.py
                ./version.py
                ./default.py
                ./local.py
                ./live.py
```

Your post pull hook would create :

```
/var/www/aweso.me/project/base/settings/version.py
```

Which would contain the latest (or previous) git commit hash :

```
__version__ = "0763j34bf"
```

Then with a simple `from .version import __version__ as ApplicationVersion` in your `settings.live`, your template tag can simply use `from settings import ApplicationVersion` to write that query parameter as teh cache buster.

Answer (score 0):

We are using this simple templatetag to generate version number based on file modification time:

```
import os
import posixpath
import stat
import urllib

from django import template
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def staticfile(path):
    normalized_path = posixpath.normpath(urllib.unquote(path)).lstrip('/')
    absolute_path = finders.find(normalized_path)
    if not absolute_path and getattr(settings, 'STATIC_ROOT', None):
        absolute_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, path)
    if absolute_path:
        return '%s%s?v=%s' % (settings.STATIC_URL, path, os.stat(absolute_path)[stat.ST_MTIME])
    return path
```

For pre 1.3 Django there is even simpler version of this tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def staticfile(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    url = '%s%s?v=%s' % (settings.MEDIA_URL, path, os.stat(file_path)[stat.ST_MTIME])
    return url
```

Usage:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%  staticfile "css/style.css" %}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Has the same issue as my original solution. Can't handle images referenced inside CSS (unless I serve CSS through Django). Hoping I can find a better way.

Comment: Yep, the question of how to best handle images in CSS files is a perennial one. You can't take advantage of `MEDIA_URL` and, as in your case, you can't add query strings or such to effect caching. That is, unless, you serve the files through Django, but that's a whole other can or worms.

Comment: However, since your question is one of invalidating caches for modified files, it's presumable that an image referenced by CSS, when modified would correspond to an edit in the CSS file, anyways. It's not necessarily and always-case, but presumably it shouldn't be too difficult to self-manage cache invalidation here.

Answer (score -1):

This might help as well: http://www.fanstatic.org/

Answer (score -1):

I think a simple solution might be:

1. Write your css files as Django templates.
2. Write a Django command to render your css-templates (and store them in somewhere accessible)
3. In your deployment script call this command.